# How much time will a TreeMap take?

Tags: java, performance, collections, time-complexity, treemap

I am using a `TreeMap` with its keys as `String` and values as a `List` of Custom objects. Something like this:

```
Map<String, List<CustomObject>> map = new TreeMap<String, List<CustomObject>>();
```

I know that insert and get operations on a TreeMap have O(log n ) time complexity. But, I am not fully aware of how to guesstimate the time taken to process a TreeMap,

Can somebody help me with the approach you would use for finding out

1. Time taken to put around 40,000  records into `TreeMap` (Consider that all Strings are random and unique).  i.e., Following line 40000 times:

   ```
   map.put("SomeString", listOfCustomObjects)
   ```
2. Time taken for iterating over the keyset once that includes a call to `get()` method:

   ```
   for(String s: map.keySet()){
       List<CustomObject> listOfCustomObjects =map.get(s);
       //do something with the list
   }
   ```

Comment: You can test for this yourself by using Google's Guava stopwatch library along with a loop that adds the record 40,000 times. Or you could even just compare System.currentTimeMillis() from before and after the loop.

Comment: Treemap is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys. Why don't you put `System.currentTimeMillis()` or nanoseconds before and after the loop of your insertion and retrieval.

Comment: Test and measure. It is impossible for anyone else to do this for you on your hardware and its configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Write the test and measure the time. There are no reliable ways of estimating execution time without actual execution.

Make sure the benchmark key distribution matches real-life key distribution, because balancing algorithms may severly influence execution time.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to estimate. Here is a little test:

```
System.out.println("put\titeration");
for (int r = 0; r < 10; ++r) {
    Map<String, List<Object>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    List<Object> dummyList = new ArrayList<>();

    long start, end, putTime, iterTime;
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; ++i) {
        map.put(String.valueOf(), dummyList);
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    putTime = (end - start);

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(String s: map.keySet()){
        List<Object> listOfCustomObjects = map.get(s);
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    iterTime = (end - start);
    System.out.println(putTime + "ms\t" + iterTime + "ms");
}
```

This test adds 1.000.000 Entries to a TreeMap. This gets repeated ten times.

Why I used 1.000.000 instead of 40.000? 40.000 are to few entrys. My results are around 40ms to 70ms. More entries leads to bigger differences between the results:

```
put     iteration
1224ms  211ms
626ms   198ms
769ms   199ms
577ms   193ms
1179ms  194ms
438ms   190ms
445ms   201ms
309ms   200ms
378ms   198ms
396ms   205ms
```

I used a 2.40 GHz CPU.

So most of the time it needs ~400ms but some times it needs two or three times more time. This is due to just in time optimization, memory management or simply because of OS process scheduling. How knows...

Answer (score 0):

Microbenchmarking is tricky and difficult. Use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), but first read the docs and some tutorials, for example [this one](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html).

So, for 1), just use JMH and see how long it takes.

Regarding 2), do the same: design a microbenchmark and see how long it takes. However, there's a much more efficient way to iterate over the entries of the map, which is to use the `Map.entrySet` method:

```
for (Entry<String>, List<CustomObjects>> e : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = e.getKey();
    List<CustomObjects> value = e.getValue();
    // do something with the list
}
```

This way is better because in a `TreeMap`, `get` has `O(log n)` time complexity, so calling `get` `n` times would be `O(n log n)`, while using the `entrySet` method is constant (`entrySet` returns a set that is a *view* of the entries of the map), and you already have the value in each entry.